# Как отформатировать текст полученный из базы данных mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Ребята здравствуйте. Учусь работать с pymysql модулем, вывожу данные из таблицы, но выводятся они как то не так. Вот запрос:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        select_name = "SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE id=1"
        cursor.execute(select_name)
        name = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in name:
            player_name = row
```

Выводит он мне не просто имя из БД, а строку вот в таком виде: 'name': 'test'
Как то можно убрать кавычки, двоеточие и отрезать name, что бы в чистом виде в переменную попадало только имя - test
Я пытался искать, пробовал с помощью s.find(":") вот такой конструкции... не получилось. Гугл не помог. Или я не правильно спрашивал.
Я новичёк в программировании, если это просто и вопрос глупый не пинайте.

UPD: Решено! Спасибо.
Просто нужно подставить индекс нужного элемента print(row[0])

Comment: В `row` у вас будет конкретная коллекция данных. Нужно из нее извлечь данные. Попробуйте: `print(row[0])` или `print(row['name'])`?

Comment: Огроменое вам человеческое спасибо! Я и не подумал что там скорее всего какой-нибудь список или кортеж... список скорее всего. Благодарю вас.

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, самостоятельно ответ на ваш вопрос с решением